# Concatenar un valor de un input con su respectivo nombre

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de utilizar un array `anexo[]` en unos formularios que cambian según el usuario que abre la página. Esto lo hice con un switch case:

```
switch ($_SESSION["idUser"]) {
            case UCOMPRAS: // COMPRAS PC
                $anexo = '
                <div class="container-sm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="anexo[]" placeholder="CFP" required>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="anexo[]" placeholder="EAN" required>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="anexo[]" placeholder="COC" required>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                ';
                break;

            case UESTAMPACION: // ESTAMPACION
                $anexo = '
                <div class="container-sm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="anexo[]" placeholder="MCS" required>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="anexo[]" placeholder="MES" required>
                        <br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="anexo[]" placeholder="CFP" required>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                ';
                break;
```

Como verán, la variable `$anexo` cambia según el tipo de usuario que abre el formulario y también envía ciertos valores según el usuario que llena los input.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo concatenar el valor de cada input con su respectivo placeholder?

Por ejemplo, mi primer input del usuario UCOMPRAS:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="anexo[]" placeholder="CFP" required>
```

debe recoger el valor de una **"CFP"**, por tanto, el usuario escribirá un número cualquiera **"12345"**. Quisiera que el valor que se enviara por POST, fuera **"CFP12345"**. ¿Cómo hago esto?

Comment: En cualquiera de los 2 casos, tienes 3 inputs, y quieres enviar al post el valor junto con el placeholder. ¿Pero como? cual sería el nombre de la propiedad a enviar? ya que hay 3 inputs y no dices ni pones un ejemplo de como sería lo que envías a la api

Comment: La base de datos recoge un valor ( $_POST["anexo"]) y lo guarda en un campo llamado "Observaciones", los input pueden variar, no siempre son 3. Quisiera  que todo lo de esos input se guardara en un gran concatenado que quede CFP123, EAN123, etc, con su respectivo titulo

Comment: Agrega tu Back de PHP, eso lo puedes hacer desde ahí y evitas tanto problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías simplemente recorrer el $_POST['anexo'] con un foreach.
Luego crear una array con los valores concatenados con el prefijo que desees.
Al finalizar el foreach, unís los elementos del array en un string separado por comas.

```
$_POST['anexo'] = $_POST['anexo'] ?? ''; // si no existe el valor, lo asigna vacio
    
    $observaciones = ''; // inicializa la variable
    
    if ($_POST['anexo']) { // si existe el valor, recorre el array
        foreach ($_POST['anexo'] as $v) { // recorre el array
            $v = 'CPF' . $v; // agrega el prefijo al valor
            $array[] = $v; // crear array con los valores
        }
        $observaciones = implode(', ', $array); // convierte el array en string
    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos.